# Uniswap Liquidity Not Showing (please advise)

Tags: uniswap, erc-20-approve

We created a meme token. Added it into the ERC20 blockchain and then went to add it to Uniswap.

Can someone please advise as to why the coin was succesfull being added to Uniswap, but will not allow to be swapped on Uniswap exchange? When trying to add ETH liquidity it simply does nothing, even Metamask won't open.

Etherscan links for reference.

https://etherscan.io/token/0x320087a0322b3c96e58f9dffb8e78540c4d3bfe9?a=0x5963ecb0d238e40a61dbd382d38a80a151e77dad

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0a658535587878c118859227620a5d0030e8ff64c6812fd4b4800c19f12e7919

Comment: there was the same error at the moment, I found an up-to-date solution to the problem - https://medium.com/@argentosalick/cant-find-liquidity-uniswap-3b3621a4c361

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because Uniswap v3 uses NFT?

I can't recall the details at this very moment, but I remember reading that in order to manage the new slippage window margin thing,  they had to use a non Fungible Token.

I'd be made it a comment if I can, because it just like a hint or a direction to look into not a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Despite the price impact it's possble to swap your token.